# how to do Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In the Visual Studio , the auto-format is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> , what does it mean ? I should hold the two keys at the same time .... ?

Can I bind another key to this weird ?

Thanks

Comment: Hold down Ctrl, hit 'K', then hit 'F'.

Comment: Well this is not exactly a programming question...

Comment: @digEmAll It is a "tools related" question, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to hold both keys at the same time. You only need to **keep** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **held down**, press <kbd>K</kbd> (release it) and then <kbd>F</kbd> (release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> now).

Comment: You don't have to keep the [Ctrl] key pressed. You can certainly release [Ctrl] after entering the first key combination and press it again for the next combination.

Comment: keep down ```ctrl``` and press ```k``` then release both ```ctrl``` as well as ```k``` and then only press ```f```. Definitely it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> first, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>.

To change it go to Tools > Customize > Keyboard and change the entry for Edit.FormatSelection.

Answer (score 3):

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, you will be prompted "waiting for a new key chord" as soon as you enter the first one

Comment: Note that this prompt message appears at the bottom blue bar

Answer (score 1):

Keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed while you first tap <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>F</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, press <kbd>K</kbd>. Release <kbd>K</kbd>, press <kbd>F</kbd> while still holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Release all.

Answer (score 0):

You would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then <kbd>K</kbd>, release <kbd>K</kbd> and then press <kbd>F</kbd>.